# HERE Maps Routing API doesn't find public transport route in some cities

Tags: here-api

I'm doing a lot of public transport route calculation with HERE Maps API in 13 german cities. I have a list of coordinates for each city and I want to calculate the travel time for public transport from each coordinate to the others inside a city.

In some cities the HERE Maps API doesn't calculate a single route and gives the error "no route found". Although the HERE Maps documentation says that public transport is covered in the cities that I chose. At the same time, the route calculation for public transport on the website wego.here.com can find a public transport route.

Here is an example of the problem for one route in the city of Regensburg:

The start coordinates are: 49.02406,12.07187

The destination coordinates are: 49.01441,12.12384

This route that is beeing calculated in the browser (wego.here.com):
[https://wego.here.com/directions/publicTransport/Clermont-Ferrand-Allee,-93049-Regensburg,-Germany:49.02399,12.07187/Straubinger-Straße-20,-Ostenviertel,-93055-Regensburg,-Germany:loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPVN0cmF1YmluZ2VyK1N0cmElQzMlOUZlKzIwO2xhdD00OS4wMTQ0MTtsb249MTIuMTIzODQ7c3RyZWV0PVN0cmF1YmluZ2VyK1N0cmElQzMlOUZlO2hvdXNlPTIwO2NpdHk9UmVnZW5zYnVyZztwb3N0YWxDb2RlPTkzMDU1O2NvdW50cnk9REVVO2Rpc3RyaWN0PU9zdGVudmllcnRlbDtzdGF0ZUNvZGU9QmF2YXJpYTtjb3VudHk9UmVnZW5zYnVyZyslMjhTdGFkdCUyOTtjYXRlZ29yeUlkPWJ1aWxkaW5nO3NvdXJjZVN5c3RlbT1pbnRlcm5hbA?map=49.01898,12.10138,14,grey&leave=1505800800000](https://wego.here.com/directions/publicTransport/Clermont-Ferrand-Allee,-93049-Regensburg,-Germany:49.02399,12.07187/Straubinger-Stra%C3%9Fe-20,-Ostenviertel,-93055-Regensburg,-Germany:loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPVN0cmF1YmluZ2VyK1N0cmElQzMlOUZlKzIwO2xhdD00OS4wMTQ0MTtsb249MTIuMTIzODQ7c3RyZWV0PVN0cmF1YmluZ2VyK1N0cmElQzMlOUZlO2hvdXNlPTIwO2NpdHk9UmVnZW5zYnVyZztwb3N0YWxDb2RlPTkzMDU1O2NvdW50cnk9REVVO2Rpc3RyaWN0PU9zdGVudmllcnRlbDtzdGF0ZUNvZGU9QmF2YXJpYTtjb3VudHk9UmVnZW5zYnVyZyslMjhTdGFkdCUyOTtjYXRlZ29yeUlkPWJ1aWxkaW5nO3NvdXJjZVN5c3RlbT1pbnRlcm5hbA?map=49.01898,12.10138,14,grey&leave=1505800800000)

And here is the error when I use the HERE Maps API:

```
{
  "_type": "ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType",
  "type": "ApplicationError",
  "subtype": "NoRouteFound",
  "details": "Error is NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED",
  "additionalData": [{
    "key": "error_code",
    "value": "NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED"
  }],
  "metaInfo": {
    "timestamp": "2017-08-28T15:52:10Z",
    "mapVersion": "8.30.73.154",
    "moduleVersion": "7.2.201734-154665",
    "interfaceVersion": "2.6.34",
    "availableMapVersion": ["8.30.73.154"]
  }
}
```

I tried to change the departure time and the "mode" = publicTransportTimeTable which won't change anything. If I set the optional parameter "walkRadius" = 4080 (meter), a route will be calculated but it contains only walking and no public transport vehicles.

My question is if there's any errors in my http request or if anybody has similar experience using the HERE Maps API for public transport.

Answer (score -1):

Available coverage for Public Transit API can be found here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/coverage-information.html

Available coverage for Routing API can be found here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/coverage-information.html

Comment: Thank you, I used this site to check wether Public Transit is available in the cities. The example that i posted is in the city of Regensburg which is also in the list of available coverage for public transit API.